# How to change the legend style in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot2 `geom_density`, and here is my code:

```
ggplot() + geom_density(data=elite_avg_business_AZ,aes(avg_star,,color='elite'),alpha=0.5) +
    geom_density(data=normal_avg_business_AZ,aes(avg_star,,color='normal'),alpha=0.5) +
    scale_colour_manual(name='names',values=c('elite'='blue','normal'='red'))
```

and I get this plot

[image: plot]

almost the diagram I wanted, but the legend is a little confusing, I wish it was a line instead of a little square.
How can I change the legend style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default legend `key_glyph` for `geom_desnity` is a rect. But you could switch to a line via argument `key_glyph = "path"` like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_density(key_glyph = "path")
```

[image]