# Change legend geom with override.aes or key_glyph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In a line or density plot, the default geom of the legend in a ggplot is an empty box. I would like to make it a filled in square (e.g. `geom_point(shape = 15)`). I know it is possible to manually specify many aspects of the legend using `aes.override()` but I can't figure out how to swap to a different geom.

I also see that `key_glyph()` may be what I need but can't figure out how to implement properly. Because `geom_density()` takes a `fill` argument (which I want to leave empty in the plot), it seems I need to separately supply a `fill` argument to the `key_glyph` but I can't figure out from the [docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/draw_key.html) how to use the `params` argument to e.g. `draw_key_rect()`.

In case it helps, I found this [closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66570353/13210554).

Is this possible? What am I doing wrong here?

```r
library(tidyverse)

p <- mtcars |> 
  ggplot(aes(disp, color = factor(cyl)))

# override.aes makes no change
p + 
  geom_density() +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(geom = "point", shape = 15)))
```

[image]

```r
# key_glyph seem to require a fill argument but don't know how to specify
p + geom_density(key_glyph = draw_key_rect)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the default fill is transparent. But an easy override is as below:

```
mtcars |> 
  ggplot(aes(disp, color = factor(cyl), fill = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_density(key_glyph = draw_key_rect, alpha = 0) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = c(1, 1, 1)))
```

Comment: Just a note. You could do `override.aes = list(alpha = 1))` if you want to assign the same value for all legend entries. Anyway, nice workaround. +1

Comment: Thanks, great insight that the issue was the default fill. I went on github to complain about the thin documentation on `draw_key_*` so I could discover the workaround and it turns out that this is being considered a [bug](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5385). So perhaps this will change in future versions.

Answer (score 2):

First, if you want to fake a rectangle guide via rectangle points using `shape=15`, you have to set the `key_glyph` to `"point"` or `draw_key_point` in `geom_density`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

mtcars |>
  ggplot(aes(disp, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_density(key_glyph = "point") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(
    override.aes = list(shape = 15, size = 5)))
```

[image]

Second, the issue with using `key_glyph="rect"` is that I requires `fill` to be set as an aesthetic or an argument. Otherwise `fill` is `NA` and you end up with blank rects. TBMK there is no mechanism to override this behavior.

Besides the workaround offered by @WilliamWong another option would be to create a custom key glyph, where the `fill` color is inherited from `color` if not set. Whether this is worthwhile the effort ... (:

```r
library(tidyverse)

"%||%" <- function(a, b) {
  if (!is.null(a)) a else b
}

# Copy & Paste from ggplot2::draw_key_rect
draw_key_cust <- function(data, params, size) {
  # make fill inherit color if NA
  if (is.na(data$fill)) data$fill <- data$col

  grid::rectGrob(
    gp = grid::gpar(
      col = NA, fill = alpha(data$fill %||%
        data$colour %||% "grey20", data$alpha),
      lty = data$linetype %||%
        1
    )
  )
}

mtcars |>
  ggplot(aes(disp, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_density(key_glyph = "cust")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It turns out this behaviour seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5385) in ggplot2. It may be possible to use some of your answer here to resolve it if you're interested. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use `draw_key_rect` without defining a new draw key or adding a dummy layer. You just need to override the `fill` aesthetic with the vector of colours used in the color scale (the default ggplot colours can be obtained with `scales::hue_pal()(3)`

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars |> 
  ggplot(aes(disp, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_density(key_glyph = draw_key_rect) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = scales::hue_pal()(3))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Haha. Yeah. Sometimes one overlooks the obvious. :D